# CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning does not remove the warning

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I'm having some problems with my automated build system using ant and Cygwin.

An ant script on PC1 uses the "sshexec" task to execute the scripts responsible for the build on PC2.

PC1 is running win7
PC2 is running winXP and using Cygwin 1.7.9, just for the ssh service.

When PC2 executes a python script from the bash shell as part of the build process I get the following output (I expect only the last line to be echo'd).

```
    build.integrity.calc:
    [echo] Calculating CRC using
    [echo] c:\projects\XXX\misc\tools/crcCalc/src/calc16bitCrc.py
    [echo] CODE CRC = cygwin warning:
    [echo] MS-DOS style path detected: c:\projects\XXX\misc\tools/crcCalc/src/calc16bitCrc.py
    [echo] Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/projects/XXX/misc/tools/crcCalc/src/calc16bitCrc.py
    [echo] CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
    [echo] Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    [echo] http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
    [echo] 0x66c8
```

I've set user and system variables CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning in windows on both PC1 and PC2, however the warning persists.

I cannot use the POSIX paths as the scripts need to also run in a pure windows environment. Looking at the output of the ${os} property does not help, as it returns the windows info from the JVM and does appear to help me distinguish between Cygwin/Windows environments.

Is there another method to ensure that the Cygwin ssh environment has the "CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning" variable set? I'm open to other ideas for working around this in (ant, different ssh, etc), though I'd prefer to just have Cygwin not issue the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a terribly helpful answer to future people having trouble with Cygwin's nodosfilewarning . However it does speak to the root of my question about distributing ant build tasks across multiple computers.

The solution I came to was to replace the Cygwin ssh with the ant-server task in the ant-contrib library. http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/server_tasks.html